# Why is a unified field theory necessary?

Tags: theory-of-everything, unified-theories

I have read almost everywhere that the biggest questions in physics is to unify all the fundamental forces but I simply do not understand why do the forces have to follow a same set of rules or why is unification of Forces necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52385/2451 and links therein.