# Is anyone attempting to disprove the existence of ToE? (Formerly: Is there necessarily a theory of everything?)

Tags: theory-of-everything, epistemology

Does the following claim have a proof?

Theorem: There exists a theory of everything.

[edit: Added the following to hopefully clarify what I’m driving at.]

Is any physicist working on proving the following theorem?

Theorem: There is no ToE because QM and GR are fundamentally irreconcilable. In other words, any theorem that addresses the question of a ToE – much as any theorem that addresses the question of perpetual motion machines – is necessarily a nogo theorem.

Comment: No. What to do?

Comment: Not yet. ......

Comment: Multiple TOEs exist. We just don’t know if any of them are correct, We do know that some are incorrect, but all you asked about was existence.

Comment: But... my associates were calling this  the [Kabelschacht](https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=a%20Kabelschacht)  equation!

Comment: Reconciling quantum theory and general relativity presents problems; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics#Relation_to_general_relativity

Comment: I don't see a reason for all the down and close votes. Why do we expect there should be a TOE, especially in the face of all the difficulties in coming up with one? It sounds like a very reasonable question.

Comment: And here is that question. [Why do we need a Theory-Of-Everything (TOE)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52385/37364)

Comment: This is a conjecture, not a theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need a Theory-Of-Everything (TOE)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52385/why-do-we-need-a-theory-of-everything-toe)

Comment: @Semoi We already know that $A = 42$.

Comment: That makes as much sense as any lecture I've heard from a string theorist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one of the most popular Theories of Everything is string theory, or M-theory. This essentially gives us a way to link general relativity to quantum mechanics by introducing the force of gravity as a particle in the standard model. This would require a certain "common factor" between gravity (the graviton), and the rest of the particles, so string theory was devised. It essentially tells us that there are "vibrations", or "strings" that make up particles, and a certain "vibration", or "combination" of these strings give us various particles. However, this would require us to have 11 dimensions. While this is a possibility that cannot be dismissed, it's certainly difficult to prove.

Then, there's the slightly less popular Loop Quantum Gravity (LQG).

> LQG postulates that the structure of space is composed of finite loops woven into an extremely fine fabric or network. These networks of loops are called spin networks. The evolution of a spin network, or spin foam, has a scale on the order of a Planck length, approximately 10−35 metres, and smaller scales are meaningless. Consequently, not just matter, but space itself, prefers an atomic structure.

The whole point of *trying* to devise a theory that could act as a bridge between QM and GR is to find a possibility for a TOE. I don't think someone would be trying to disprove the need for a TOE when there's an obvious need for it - the inconsistencies between QM and GR.

For one, GR tells us that each cause results in a predictable, local effect. It tells us that each object has a specific, precise point in time that can be measured. However, QM tells us that events in the subatomic realm have *probabilistic*, rather than definite outcomes.

This is just one of the many inconsistencies between QM and GR. I hope you now understand the need for one.

Comment: But for all we know, there is no such bridge between QM and GR. A "need" for it is just a personal preference, correct? A unification of QM and GR, if such a thing exists - and I doubt that it does - would simply pacify people who include aesthetic criteria in their evaluation of scientific theories even though mother nature herself doesn't seem to care.

Comment: From an article on theguardian.com: "Relativity gives nonsensical answers when you try to scale it down to quantum size, eventually descending to infinite values in its description of gravity. Likewise, quantum mechanics runs into serious trouble when you blow it up to cosmic dimensions." That's not difficult; just don't use relativity at quantum scale. Likewise, don't use QM at cosmic dimensions. Engineers ignore QM when building bridges because good old fashioned Newtonian mechanics works just fine. The so-called unification of physics isn't a scientific endeavor, but an aesthetic one.

Comment: If a theory of everything *is* developed, you are correct in that QM and GR will still continue to be fantastic models at their respective scales, simply because they make excellent predictions, and are likely to be a whole lot easier than invoking the full ToE all the time! But a theory of everything will necessarily make predictions that QM and GR don't - perhaps at very, very high energy scales, but measurable nonetheless. Whether or not these will have any ramifications in technology etc. is hard to say - but they are predictions nonetheless and not just "aesthetics" as you put it.

Comment: @HankIgoe You're right, _as of now_ there isn't any bridge between the two. However, as NiharKarve says, it's not just "aesthetics", there's a genuine need to solve inconsistencies between the two. Yes, you cannot apply QM to cosmic dimensions and GR to quantum dimensions; each of them work well at their own scales. But we need a way to link both of the two. The inconsistencies in the standard model, for one, could be solved using GR, if a mathematical link existed between the two, instead of using purely quantum solutions to a non-quantum problem with quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks to Akhilesh and Nihar for the excellent answers.

Answer (score 1):

It has no proof at present. So far, all attempts at constructing a "T.O.E." have failed, and constructing one that is testable is extremely difficult, since a true TOE has to govern phenomena which occur at energy scales which none of our test tools can reach.

It is a complicated business which is engaging some of the greatest minds in physics, and they are working on it despite there being no proof that the task is doable.